# Rsync ignore time comparison

Tags: rsync

What are the flags to make sure rsync ignore modification time and use checksum only?

Answer (score 10):

From the `rsync(1)` man page:

> ```
>     -c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
>        ...
>     -I, --ignore-times          don’t skip files that match size and time
> ```

As always, `-n` will help you make sure you have the options you need.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding "don't skip" in this context, but I wouldn't deny that it's not clear.

Comment: if working from different computers, cloning from git will set the time you cloned as the mod time... which means everything will look changed to rsync by default... checksum may be a better option in those instances.

Answer (score 3):

After some time of trying, I found this one is more useful.

Sync two folders ignoring timestamp changes:

```
rsync --dry-run -icrvh from_path to_path
```

Remove `--dry-run` once you like what will be synched.

- `-i` is for showing information of changes. See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037164/2215679)
- `-c` perform checksum check
- `-r` recursive
- `-v` verbose
- `-h` human readable numbers. eg: 1K instead of 1,024